# Vertical Poles - Advanced Geometry Problem

Tags: geometry

Two vertical poles $20$ feet and $80$ feet high are $100$ feet apart. Ropes connect the top of each pole with the base of the other pole. At what height, in feet, do these ropes intersect?

I keep getting $14$ as my answer, but this is clearly wrong. I tried doing some random things - but to no avail. I would like to see a solution to how such a problem is done.

Thanks!

Comment: Would you mind explaining what have you tried?

Comment: I thought 400/25 = 14, whoops lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

In the above diagram, we want to find $h$. To do this, we create new variables $x,y$ as follows : from the point of intersection of the ropes $B$, drop a perpendicular until it hits the ground. This point we call $F$. Let $x = EF$ and $y = DF$. Clearly, $x+y = 100$.

Note that triangles $BFE$ and $CDE$ are similar, since they are both right angled, and contain the common angle $\angle DEC = \angle FEB$. So, by the sides being in ratio, we get:
$$
\frac{BF}{FE} = \frac{CD}{DE} \implies \frac hx = \frac{80}{100}=\frac 45
$$

Similarly, we get that triangles $BFD$ and $AED$ are similar, being right angled and sharing the angle $\angle ADE = \angle BDF$. So, again by sides being in ratio:
$$
\frac{BF}{FD} = \frac{AE}{ED} \implies \frac hy = \frac{20}{100} = \frac 15
$$

Combined with $x+y = 100$ and the previous equations, we get $5h = 4x$ and $5h = y$, so:
$$
400 = 4(x+y) = 4x+4y = 5h + 20h = 25h \implies h = \frac{400}{25} = 16 
$$

and thence comes the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A,B$ be the top and bottom of the first pole and $D,E$ be the top and bottom of the second pole. Let $C = AE \cap BD$. You have $\triangle ACB \sim \triangle ECD\implies \dfrac{AC}{EC} = \dfrac{CB}{CD}$. Let $h$ be the height of $C$ (to the ground), then: $\dfrac{h}{20} = \dfrac{EC}{EA} \implies \dfrac{20-h}{h} =\dfrac{AC}{EC}, \dfrac{h}{80} = \dfrac{BC}{BD}\implies \dfrac{h}{80-h}=\dfrac{CB}{CD}$. Thus: $\dfrac{20-h}{h} = \dfrac{h}{80-h}\implies h^2= (h-20)(h-80)=h^2-100h+1600\implies h = 16$ .